# installing NopCommerce Categories Header menu in NopCommerce 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, plugins, menu, nopcommerce

i was trying to integrate [Category Header Menu](http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1015/nop-categories-header-menu-nop-templates.aspx) in my NopCommerce 3.0 site, but unfortunately that could not be installed. I followed following steps

1) i downloaded it then unzipped

2) Copied the Unzipped folder under Plugins folder

3) From admin `Settings--> General And Miscellaneous--> Made the menu Active`

But i can't still see the category header menu in my store site. can anybody please provide a pointer. what i am missing or not doing it in correct manner.

Any help would be appreciated much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your plugin is installed. You can do that by going to Configuration > Plugin, and find Header Menu in the list.